# Gas logs will not ignite

Tags: gas, fireplace

I have gas logs that will not light.  I do see the spark when I push the button.  However, when I hold down the pilot button for an extended period of time I get no fire or flame and I also do not hear or smell the gas.

If I turn the gas to “on” however I do hear and smell gas.

Any idea of what may be the issue an any tricks to get it back to working?

[image]

Comment: This, as expected, looks similar to a gas cooktop burner. A typical gas cooktop burner has a *burner cap* which covers the gas supply and the igniter which effectively makes sure the gas will actually flow near the igniter. If that cap is not on, the igniter will spark but the gas will usually not ignite (or at least not in the usual controlled manner...) Is there possibly a missing part?

Comment: No missing parts that I know of.  This was working until about a year ago and I assumed we ran out of gas.  This is for secondary heat.  I refilled it this week and have not been able to start

Comment: you might have to "light" it first, for 10-30 seconds, to heat up a thermal safety valve in/by the pilot that cuts off the pilot when it goes out.